# Visual C# Collection "map" function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, collections, dictionary

In Haskell we have the function

```
map (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

to change the type of a Collection using a function.

Is there something similar in C#?

Or what else is the fastest way to put a complete collection of KeyValuePairs into a debug message, for example?

I thought of sth like

```
debugmsg("http response is " + service.HttpResponseHeaders
                                      .Map<string>((k, v) => k + "->" + v)
                                      .Aggregate((s, sx) => s + "," + sx)
                             + ". ");
```

Comment: Note that a header can have multiple values. Simply concatenating the value won't work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In LINQ, `map` is named `Select`. Also, please note that any collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` will have only one argument in `Select`; you'll have to pull the `Key` and `Value` out of it.

```
service.HttpResponseHeaders.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + "->" + kvp.Value)
                           .Aggregate((s, sx) => s + "," + sx);
```

Comment: Value is an IEnumerable<string>. Simply concatenating strings will result in "String[]" instead of the actual value

Comment: If it's the case (that the `Value` from key-value pair is a collection), then doing `SelectMany` a.k.a `flatMap` on the value should solve the issue.

Comment: Not really, you need to combine a single header name with multiple values. A single operation is not enough.

Comment: Doing `kvp => kvp.Key + "->" + string.Join("-", kvp.Value)` should be good enough then. The question was about `map` though...

Answer (score 1):

LINQ comes with `Select`

Signature (Haskell style):

```
IEnumerable<TSource>.Select(Func<TSource->TResult>)->IEnumerable<TResult>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Dictionary`, which is basically a collection of `KeyValuePair`s and do something like:

```
service.HttpResponseHeaders
                  .Select(kvp => kvp.Key + " -> " + String.Join(" - ", kvp.Value))
                  .Aggregate((s, sx) => s + ", " + sx);
```

Optimizing Aggregate: [Optimizing Aggregate for String Concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354587/optimizing-aggregate-for-string-concatenation)

Comment: HttpResponseHeaders is also a collection of KeyValuePair, actually it implements IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>. No need for Dictionary, and string concatenation will return "String[]", not the header value

Comment: Then call `.Aggregate()` on your value. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: A String.Join would be simpler and faster, because it wouldn't create any temporary strings

Comment: Are you sure .Aggregate() does? Why shouldn't it use the `StringBuilder` also?

Comment: Apart from the DRY, just try it and see how ugly it looks

Comment: Calling .Aggregate() two times doesn't hurt the DRY-principle, imo. And the result is the same as using String.Join().

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you can map one type to another using Select. Creating the final string is best done using [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) though, to avoid creating useless temporary strings.

Strings in .NET are immutable so adding two strings creates a new string. String.Join on the other hand uses a StringBuilder internally to add data to a mutable buffer and return the final result.

You should note though that [HttpResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpresponseheaders%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains multiple values for each key. Just converting the value to a string will not work.

The following will create a comma-separated list of values from the response headers. If the header has multiple values, they are separated by '|':

```
var headerStrings=from header in service.HttpResponseHeaders
            let headerValue=String.Join("|",header.Value)
            select String.Format("{0} -> {1}",header.Key,headerValue);
var message=String.Join(",",headerStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Select()` or if it is a List you can use `.ConvertAll()`

Here is the MSDN Documentation

[Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[List.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)